# Msil Emit static array in dynamic type

Tags: c#, arrays, static, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create a new type using  Reflection.Emit (in c#).

The code I want to create is something similar to

```
public class 
{
   public static int[] A = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
}
```

I first tried to define a field, and then set its value:

```
var fb = tb.DefineField("A", FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
fb.SetValue(null, new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```

but it doesn't work, since setValue is only supported for simple types (int, float, ...).

Now I'm trying to use DefineInitializedData (much longer code which doesn't work...), but it does not generate any valid IL code.

Comment: My general advice would be to code what you want to to achieve in C#, disassemble it with ildasm, and then look at the output for ideas.

Comment: Have you defined the type of A? `DefineField("A", FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static)` seems to have the Type parameter missing, or am I missing something?

Comment: @nXu That's likely just a copy&paste error. You really can't use `SetValue()` like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> setValue is only supported for simple types (int, float, ...)

No, it's not. `FieldBuilder` inherits `SetValue()` from `FieldInfo`, but it doesn't make sense for `FieldBuilder`.

There is [`FieldBuilder.SetConstant()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.fieldbuilder.setconstant), but it only works for `const` fields. And you can't have `const` fields of reference types with values other than `null`.

What you need to do is the same thing any compiler would have to do: create a static constructor, create the array there and then assign it to the field:

```
var fb = tb.DefineField("A", typeof(int[]), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);

var ctor = tb.DefineTypeInitializer();

var il = ctor.GetILGenerator();

// new int[3]
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(int));

// array[0] = 1
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

// array[1] = 2
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

// arr[2] = 3
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

// A = array
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, fb);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

If you look at the decompiled code generated by the C# compiler, you might see different IL, using something like `<PrivateImplementationDetails>.__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=12` and [`RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.initializearray). That's an optimization and I think that if you're writing IL by hand, it's going to be simpler to use the normal method I showed above.

Comment: thanks. I'd prefer having this optim, but I guess everything will be fine with the version you propose.

Comment: a few comments to get that working completely. 

instead of Dup, it's better to load the field
`cbilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, fb);`

the storeField must be at the beginning. 
Many thanks though!