# How to initialize static init-only field of dynamic type in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, reflection.emit, .net-core-3.0

Calling `fieldBuilder.SetValue(...)` is currently not supported [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.fieldbuilder?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). The documentation advices:

> As a workaround, retrieve the FieldInfo by reflecting on the finished
>   type and call SetValue to set the value of the field.

This was possible in .NET Framework for static init-only fields, however this is [no longer supported in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11571#issuecomment-442675193).

How to initialize static init-only field of dynamic type in .NET Core?

**Edit (added sample):**

```
var fb = builder.DefineField("foo", typeof(object), FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.PrivateScope | FieldAttributes.InitOnly);
// fb.SetValue(...) <-- not supported according to the doc

var c = builder.DefineTypeInitializer().GetILGenerator()
// is it possible to pass myInstance directly to type initializer?

var t = builder.CreateType();
var f = t.GetField("foo", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
f.SetValue(null, myInstance); // <-- not longer works in .NET Core
```

Comment: [From that issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11571#issuecomment-442706241): "Mutating readonly statics was never reliable, even in .NET Framework, due to JIT optimizations. If your code was mutating readonly statics, it has been broken in unpredictable ways for years. Your code could have been using old value of the readonly static depending on many factors." So the short answer is "you don't, fix your code"; the long(er) answer is "you can upvote that issue and leave a comment pleading for this to come back".

Comment: @JeroenMostert I do **not** want to **mutate** it, I want to **initialize** it.

Comment: The only safe and supported place to do so is from the static constructor. If you have a need to do it from there, but dynamically, that would be unusual -- typically you'd also be generating the static constructor in that case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So the only way to initialize static fields of dynamic type is to emit static constructor?

Comment: That has basically always been the case -- if you write a static initializer "manually", what happens is that the compiler gathers up the code for it and prepends it to the body of the static constructor (creating one if you didn't write one yourself). What exactly happens in the background if you use `.SetValue` on the reflected type isn't clear to me, but presumably that would try to skirt around the `readonly`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The problem with emitting static constructor is, that I am unable to pass an explicit instance to a static init-only field.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is -- static fields aren't attached to instances, obviously. Showing code that fails might help. Bottom line: if your static field is `initonly`, the only place to initialize it is the cctor, and then you can't have any parameters; if you want to set it arbitrarily after class initialization, then don't make the field `initonly`. The ability to set `initonly` fields through reflection has never worked reliably, and Core closes that hole.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated the question with simple code.

Comment: Is it vital to your scenario that the field is `initonly`? Normally this is a fairly easy requirement to drop, since you can always encapsulate the field behind a read-only property. To do what you want otherwise needs either indirection, that is, reading the field from a non-`initonly` static location somewhere else (like a field on another class, which doesn't have to be generated dynamically), or by moving the code that produces `myInstance` into the cctor (that is, generate more code dynamically, until there are no more dependencies).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Currently as a workaround I have dropped `initonly`. Reading from non-generated class or producing value in cctor is not possible as `myInstance` is input argument of the generator. (Each type call gets own value.) The problem is that .NET Core dropped a bad feature that was "official?" workaround for missing feature. They might first implement `FieldBuilder.SetValue` and then remove this bad feature. :-/

Comment: Each type call can still get its own value -- the cctor runs when the class is initialized, and you can force initialization by reading the generated field after you've created the type. You can use the same indirect field for all types you generate; each will copy the value at the time of initialization only. This won't work if the type has to be loaded "later", but since you were explicitly setting the field before at the time of generation, I'm going to assume that's not an issue.

Comment: Implementing `FieldBuilder.SetValue` would not solve anything, because the core problem is and would remain that an `initonly` field can only be safely initialized in a  constructor. There is no magic that `FieldBuilder.SetValue` could use to get around this -- if it were to be implemented, it would have to be done by generating initialization code in a constructor, which is exactly what you can already do on your own! (The fact that this is complicated and interferes with constructor generation is probably the reason it hasn't been implemented in the first place.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert *"You can use the same indirect field for all types you generate; each will copy the value at the time of initialization only."* I am not sure that I would like to use this "dirty" hack:) I think I will stay with no `initonly` until someone find cleaner solution.

Comment: Maybe `DefineInitializedData` could help? Someone has already been trying to exploit this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505200/msil-emit-static-array-in-dynamic-type

Comment: `DefineInitializedData`, per the docs, puts data in the `.sdata` section of the executable. In other words, the data so defined must be representable as simple bytes. That means a reference to an instance of an object is out of the question. If you can serialize the object somehow (and deserialize it in the cctor), you could use it, but it can't be a drop-in replacement. The C# compiler uses this only for `static readonly` arrays of primitive types, which then get hydrated into arrays in the cctor.

Comment: Of course, if serializing the object *is* an option, a much easier approach than futzing around with initialized data is to just generate the code for creating it in the cctor, as mentioned before, which you already shot down as not possible. But it might be an option if the object is serializable (or can be made so).

Comment: @JeroenMostert As type of the field is a reference type, the field will does not contain the object itself, but rather the reference to it. It might be possible to store there just the reference. (But I am not sure how.)

Comment: That is extremely hacky and dangerous because serializing the reference that way bypasses the garbage collector. (You can use `GCHandle` and `.To/FromIntPtr`, but then you have to pay very careful attention to when you invalidate it.) Yes, you can do it; no, you probably shouldn't. Even my hacky approach of bouncing it through another static field that changes every time is preferable to that!

Comment: Ok, better to forget `initonly`, at least for now.